# Как решить простую задачу через битовые операции?

Tags: c++

Не приходят идеи о том, как решить данную задачу с помощью битовых операций. Через if-ы нельзя.

> **Прямоугольник**
> Пете необходимо выбрать на плоскости **4** точки так, чтобы они образовывали прямоугольник со сторонами, параллельными
> осям координат. Петя уже выбрал три точки и уверен, что он выбрал их
> правильно. Помогите Пете найти координаты четвертой точки.
>
> **Входные данные**
> Содержит три строки. Каждая строка содержит два натуральных числа, разделенных пробелом - координаты одной из вершин
> прямоугольника. Все координаты лежат в диапазоне от 1 до 1000.
>
> **Выходные данные**
> Вывести два целых числа - координаты четвертой вершины прямоугольника.
>
> Лимит времени 1 секунда
> Лимит использования памяти 64 М1В
>
> ```
> Входные данные #1 Выходные данные #1
> 5 5                 7 7
> 5 7
> 7 5
> Входные данные #2 Выходные данные #2
> 2 2                 2 1
> 1 2
> 1 1
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте исключающее ИЛИ.

Координаты прямоугольника - всегда 2 пары.
По 2 пары одинаковых координат x и y.

То, чего не хватает, можно выяснить с помощью xor:

```
x = x1^x2^x3;
y = y1^y2^y3;
```

Одинаковые координаты исключат друг друга, а третья включит нужные биты.